# SQL Server schema names to CLR namespaces in EF code generation

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following tables in my database:

```
Business.Profiles
User.Profiles
```

where 'Business' and 'User' are schema.

When generating the DbContext via Ado.Net DbContext Generator(Add code generation item) I get two classes in code:

```
Profile
Profile1
```

Ideally I would have liked the the Schema names get converted to clr namespaces but that did not happen. Is there some way of forcing something like this? How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DbContext Generator only uses names specified in EDMX file so I guess you have `Profile` and `Profile1` entity defined in EDMX.

Classes must have exactly the same name as entities in EDMX and you cannot map two classes with the same name to the same EDMX model. EF doesn't support it because POCO classes are mapped by convention which uses just the name of class (EF don't use CLR namespace in mapping). Because of that you cannot achieve what you want. The simples workaround is simply naming your entities in EDMX `UserProfile` and `BusinessProfile`.

Comment: I've always found this a rather problematic organizational drawback. Workarounds aside, schemas are often used for DB namespacing; having a 1-to-1 mapping between namespaced classes and schema objects would be so much nicer.